# Why does exp(iπ) return 1 instead of -1?

Tags: c, complex-numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

const long double PI = acos(-1);
int main() {
    double complex z = exp(PI*I);
    printf("%lf %lf", crealf(z), cimagf(z));

    return 0;
}
```

We know that `exp((pi)(i))` should be `cos(pi) + i*sin(pi) = -1`, then why is the output 1 when I run this program?

Comment: Don't use `long double` if the function returns `double` and moreover, don't use `"%lf"` for a `float` or a `double`, just use `"%f"`. Also, use `M_PI` a predefined macro for the value of PI

Comment: Use `cexp` instead of `exp`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I used `%f` and `const double PI = acos(-1);` , but output is  still 1.0000000 0.0000000

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - woah, that totally worked, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: @johndoe Do what BLUEPIXY said. Also, `M_PI` is a predefined macro with a `double` value of *PI*.

Comment: `cexp()` is for complex numbers?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi - `M_PI` is not a standard macro; perhaps your platform provides it as a (non-standard) extension?  It's not available for portable code.

Comment: Disappointing that `gcc-7 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` doesn't give any diagnostic for the attempt to call `exp(double complex)`.  :-(

Comment: [double complex cexp( double complex z )](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/cexp) , [double      exp( double arg )](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/exp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code misspelt `cexp` or `cexpl` as `exp`.

In C, these functions are declared as

```
long double complex cexpl(long double complex z);
double complex cexp(double complex z);
double exp(double arg);
```

In **C++**, all of the above (and more) are available as `std::exp()`.  But **C** doesn't support overloading, so it's your responsibility as a programmer to choose the one that's appropriate for your arguments, otherwise you'll find that the input value is converted (using a narrowing conversion, if necessary).  This means that the imaginary part of `z` is lost, leaving `exp(0)` in your code.

Comment: Similar issue with `const long double PI = acos(-1);` where `acosl()` is expected to form a `long double` π.

Comment: That line already gives me `warning: initializer element is not a constant expression [-Wpedantic]`, and the result of `exp()` is narrowed to `double complex`, so the inconsistencies are everywhere - that's why I didn't attempt a full replacement program.